# Java hierarchical object connection

Tags: java

This is the structure I have at the moment:

```
Map<String,Map<Collection<Item>,Map<String,Collection<Item>>>>
```

So I have : lots of strings, that each is linked to lots of items, that each has lots of strings, that each hold lots of items.

It is rather confusing, Is there something liked a linkedlist, that can hold different types of data in this hierarchical way?

**One way to do it is to create an object, but I will be using this variable only once in my massive code, don't want to make a class for that.**

Comment: You should better create a Custom class, with fields:-  `String` and `Collection<Item>`. it would be much easier for you.

Comment: Could you describe what actual real-world problem has caused you to want such a monstrosity?  That might help us pick apart what you should _actually_ use.

Comment: `don't want to make a class for that.` -> Then may lord save you. Why don't you want to create a class. Even if you are using it for once. It will far more easier to work with.

Comment: `Map<Collection<Item>` is not a map.

Comment: @BheshGurung. Its `Map<Collection<Item>,Map<String,Collection<Item>>>` if you see clearly I know it's hard, but you can give it a try. ;)

Comment: Make a class does not necessary to be widely reusing.  Making code easier to read and give better semantic meaning is already a good reason to make a class for that.  Have a private inner class for that if you don't want to expose it to outside

Comment: @RohitJain: I got it. I don't know how the overall code will look with that kind of stuff.

Comment: My eyes are crying. Try to enclose the whole thing in a `Set` just to be sure.

Comment: Don't be afraid of classes.  Also, are you sure you need a map for this?  This structure is particularly unusual: Map<Collection<Item>,...>  Do you need to look up the ... by its key, a Collection of Items?  It that collection of items were to change, a HashMap would break here, I think.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Well lets say for I have a issue in my issuetracker. That Issue has collection of subtasks, and each subtask, has collection of links, which each have a parent. So Grouping the links by parent. It does give some scenario of what I am dealing with.

Comment: Up there I see an issue in your issuetracker ;)

Comment: Also i would compare your problem to an airbag in cars. They are made to be used only once, but still they are not just some parts they found put together, they are designed and crafted to fit special needs. So should be the code we write - I wouldn't want to see my code crashing because such a monstrous map, rather design a, or a few easy classes that do the job correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you don't wan't create class, so you are really in trouble because this is classic structure I see many times & there is no readymade generic solution for this. [Many people are dying to get such API, but :( ] Still will give you some options:

1) If you don't want to create separate class & need it for limited use, then create inner class in existing class & use it in that class itself. So no additional files created & still you get freedom of your own design.

2) If you want readymade, then closest you can get is swing tree api. It is mainly designed for swing tree components but it can be used outside also. It won't do any harm. But here you will need swing jar in  your application.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html